# linking shared libraries Scons

Tags: dynamic, linker, shared, scons

Can anybody suggest how to link shared libraries using SCons in this specific case.

I have 2 folder locations currently:

1. slib/ which contains only static libraries
2. dlib/ which contains only dynamic libraries

I can only add the prebuilt libraries to slib folder. 
dlib folder is reserved for the dynamic libraries i create from source code.
My executable always links against this dlib folder.

Now in my case, I want to add some shared libraries (not built by me) into slib folder but I want those libraries to land in dlib folder so that my executable finds it when linking. In short i want my application (requiring those shared libraries) to use one folder when compiling and different folder when running.

Is there a way in SCons I can regenerate those libraries in a different folder ?

I am not allowed to manually copy from source to destination nor i can use

```
InstallAs( target = 'XYZ/dlib',   source = 'ABC/slib' )
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I want those libraries to land in dlib", but then you say you can't copy them there, and you can't use Install?  Any reason you don't just list slib in your LIBPATH after dlib? What do you mean "regenerate those libraries in a different folder"?

Comment: the software is supposed to run on hardware. only the dlib folder is sync'd to hardware, currently slib folder only has prebuilt static libraries so it does not create any lining problem as the executable already has the definitions when running but i want to add support of adding prebuilt shared libraries too

Comment: Would the prebuilt shared libraries normally be built by the logic? Why not just put them in the dlib dir then?

Comment: When you say "Is there a way in SCons I can regenerate those libraries in a different folder ?" what libraries are you talking about?

Comment: prebuilt shared libraries are being built by some other group, any library taken from external must be put in slib folder. libraries i am talking about are these same prebuilt shared libraries which i want to get copied/regenerated into dlib

Comment: Do you want to copy them, or regenerate them (re build is the way I"m interpreting this)?

Comment: Yes regenerate. I do not want to use InstallAs

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all these clarifications?